# Specific device not receiving Google Cloud Messaging notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, device, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application where I'm implementing `Google Cloud Messaging` notifications, but in a specific device the messages don't arrive. This device has the minimum requirements to use GCM *(Android version 2.2, Play Store installed and an Google Account logged)*. In the log I see that the device is receiving the registration id and sending to the back-office where I have a list of devices registered.

My question is: Do I need to make extra configurations to make the device receive these notifications?

**Here is the manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.testegcm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="TesteGCM"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >        

        <receiver
            android:name="br.com.testegcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver" 
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="br.com.testegcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="br.com.testegcm.GcmIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="br.com.testegcm.Home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/notitle" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please include your code (manifest, broadcast receiver, etc...). Some errors in the manifest can cause the messages not to be received only on older Android versions.

Comment: @Eran I included the manifest

Answer (score 3):

Change this :

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

to :

```
<permission android:name="br.com.testegcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="br.com.testegcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the same issue and i eventually i realized that i need to change in the manifest, the broadcast receiver package name from  com.example.gcm to my package name :

```
 <!-- Push notifcations-->
        <receiver
                android:name=".BroadcastRecivers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

To

```
<!-- Push notifcations-->
        <receiver
                android:name=".BroadcastRecivers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="MY PACKAGE NAME"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly enough, simple and obvious fix. Was working for me in devices >= API 19 w/ the top, but wasn't working w/ API 15 until I made the bottom change. Apparently the latter was more strict. I had lazily copied example code and not realized I was using an example pkg name.

Answer (score 0):

**No** apart from **Android version 2.2, Play Store app installed and an Google Account logged in** no other configuration is needed, Now there are only two cases left

```
1) Either there is some ambiguity in your code. 
2) or may be it is a device specific issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem.My code would work on nexus4(Kitkat) but would fail to get me a notification from the appln server(via gcm server).For versions less that 4.0.4 you should make sure that you have your google account setup on your device for gcm to work. I had google account on my phone but the mistake I made was that my Account and Sync settings in my galaxy ace was 'Off'.When I turned it ON and ran my code, i received the notification.

Comment: In my case the Sync is ON, so the problem is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following solution. if still didn't work, let me know.
Add RECEIVE and REGISTRATION Intent in two different intent filters

```
<receiver
            android:name=“<.GCM BroadcastReceiver Name>“  // Name of your BroadcastReceiver, define in code.                                                                                                         
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>  
               <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
               <category android:name=“<Package Name>" />
            </intent-filter>
                 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name=“<Package Name>" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=“<.GCM IntentService Name>" />  // Name of your IntentService, define in code.
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Add RECEIVE and REGISTRATION Intent in two different intent filters as shown as above otherwise it won’t work for some devices(Ex. HTC).